# How do I map data from a DTO to a navigational property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I have two models, User and Review, which have a one to many relationship. I am using a DTO to create new reviews in my controller. Reviews are added to an ICollection of type Review on a Movie model, (movies and reviews also have a one to many relationship). Here's a snippet from my controller:

```
var query = db.Movies.Where(i => i.id == reviewDTO.movieId).FirstOrDefault();
            Review review = new Review()
            {
                goreRating = reviewDTO.goreRating,
                shockRating = reviewDTO.shockRating,
                jumpRating = reviewDTO.jumpRating,
                plotRating = reviewDTO.plotRating,
                supernaturalRating = reviewDTO.supernaturalRating,
                description = reviewDTO.description,
                isSpoiler = reviewDTO.isSpoiler
            };
            try
            {

                query.Reviews.Add(review);
            }
```

And the models:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public int goreRating { get; set; }
        public int shockRating { get; set; }
        public int jumpRating { get; set; }
        public int plotRating { get; set; }
        public int supernaturalRating { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public bool isSpoiler { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I add the relationship in the controller using entity framework and set the foreign key userId for each review?

Comment: "How can I add the relationship in the controller " could you pls explain what it means? And where is the controller?

Comment: I think that `Review` only needs `UserId` (int) as a foreign key property belonging to its `User` property.

Comment: you need to define relationship correctly.

Comment: @Serge What I mean is that after I define the relationship using Entity Framework, how do I then retrieve and store this relationship? Part of the controller is included on the question, the full thing is not because I wasn't sure it was all relevent and there's a lot of code there.

Comment: @GertArnold I thought Entity Framework managed this automatically? I understand how it usually works, but I want to consistently use EF's navigational properties to achieve this

Comment: @AVTUNEY Could you expand on how the relationship is defined incorrectly and how it should look? This is part of my question

Comment: *I want to consistently use EF's navigational properties* -- Then you must get the `User` and add the review to its `Reviews`. Just setting an FK property saves a roundtrip.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! I will be happy to accept this as an answer if you submit it as one @GertArnold

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a conceptual objection against using reference properties alone (aka *independent associations*) vs also adding the primitive foreign key property (aka *foreign key associations*). The latter makes many things so much easier. Keep in mind that the EF class model is a data access layer, not a domain model. It's only in DDD that we wouldn't want such properties.

Answer (score 0):

To add a relation between `User` and `Review` you are just missing the `UserId` in `Review`

```
public class Review
    {
....
        public int UserId { get; set; } // Add this to review model
....
    }
```

To get users with all their reviews you can write use this kind of LINQ query

```
var data = _context.User.Where(x => ...any condition here...).Include(x => x.Reviews )
```

Comment: I thought with Entity Framework this UserId would be automatically added to the table because there's a navigational property?

Comment: If you need `UserId` explicitly without using `Include` then you need to add this property.

Comment: I see. How would I use include in this scenario?

Comment: *then you need to add this property* That's not correct, it's possible to use a reference property only, also with `Include` (why not?). But then you have to set a `User` object (which must be attached to the context) or add the review to an attached `User`'s `Reviews` collection. Quite a hassle compared to just setting a foreign key. So I agree with adding this `UserId` property but the explanation isn't 100% correct. It's not *required* for a working relationship.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, this explains it better for me. So it's possible for me to implement, but it's effectively more work with no benefit? Other answers confused me because I knew it was possible but an explanation of why it's not preferable was also needed.